# Find documents matching one but not all of array

Tags: mongodb

Given a collection named favorites, like this:

```
[
{
    "_id" : NUUID("575fbfca-688b-497f-8e88-c14834b2a0b8"),
    "Version" : 5,
    "Name" : "Default Favorites List",
    "SpeciesIds" : [ 1000, 2000, 3000 ],
    "UserId" : "84f059e8-90b3-47b8-a03a-1bbe90ad59a4"
},

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : NUUID("75eff3df-0457-49c7-ade2-141fa75d526e"),
    "Version" : 15,
    "Name" : "Super Secret List",
    "SpeciesIds" : [ 1000, 4000, 5000 ],
    "UserId" : "84f059e8-90b3-47b8-a03a-1bbe90ad59a4"
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : NUUID("1aa5d3d2-3056-4b73-ace9-f1e56fd77329"),
    "Version" : 5,
    "Name" : "Cool list",
    "SpeciesIds" : [ 
        2000, 3000, 6000
    ],
    "UserId" : "84f059e8-90b3-47b8-a03a-1bbe90ad59a4"
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : NUUID("98ee31fb-509b-4635-ac1a-564b7b34beb9"),
    "Version" : 1,
    "Name" : "Galaxy S4",
    "SpeciesIds" : [ 
        4000, 5000, 6000
    ],
    "UserId" : "84f059e8-90b3-47b8-a03a-1bbe90ad59a4"
},

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : NUUID("2297dcb8-c135-499e-98cb-b6cf80449bd2"),
    "Version" : 3,
    "Name" : "Meta List",
    "SpeciesIds" : [ 
        1000, 9000, 10000, 5555, 33333
    ],
    "UserId" : "84f059e8-90b3-47b8-a03a-1bbe90ad59a4"

}
]
```

I need to build a query that returns documents that have at least one of the SpeciesIds array, but doesn't match all of the items in the SpeciesIds array.

I was able to build the first part that matches it if it has a least one, but not the "not all" part.  It's giving me an error, unexpected token : .

```
db.favorites.find(
{
     SpeciesIds: {$in: [1000, 2000, 3000]}, 
     SpeciesIds: { $nor: [ $all: [1000, 2000, 3000]]}
});
```

The results should be:

```
[
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : NUUID("75eff3df-0457-49c7-ade2-141fa75d526e"),
    "Version" : 15,
    "Name" : "Super Secret List",
    "SpeciesIds" : [ 1000, 4000, 5000 ],
    "UserId" : "84f059e8-90b3-47b8-a03a-1bbe90ad59a4"
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : NUUID("1aa5d3d2-3056-4b73-ace9-f1e56fd77329"),
    "Version" : 5,
    "Name" : "Cool list",
    "SpeciesIds" : [ 
        2000, 3000, 6000
    ],
    "UserId" : "84f059e8-90b3-47b8-a03a-1bbe90ad59a4"
},
/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : NUUID("2297dcb8-c135-499e-98cb-b6cf80449bd2"),
    "Version" : 3,
    "Name" : "Meta List",
    "SpeciesIds" : [ 
        1000, 9000, 10000, 5555, 33333
    ],
    "UserId" : "84f059e8-90b3-47b8-a03a-1bbe90ad59a4"
}
]
```

It excludes the first one because *ALL* 3 of it's elements match

What is the correct syntax to pull this off?  I should mention that this is mongodb 2.6.6

Comment: Negative, that won't do partial matches.  If an element has 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 and we search for 1000, 2000, 3000, it will match it because the arrays aren't the same, but all of the search parameters are in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the condition with second `SpeciesIds` condition.

```
db.favorites.find(
{
     SpeciesIds: {$in: [1000, 2000, 3000]}, 
     SpeciesIds: { $nor: [ $all: [1000, 2000, 3000]]}
});
```

Instead of the above query, it should be like that:

```
db.getCollection('stack').find({
    $and: [{
        SpeciesIds: {
            $in: [1000, 2000, 3000]
        }
    }, {
        SpeciesIds: {
            $not: {
                $all: [1000, 2000, 3000]
            }
        }
    }]
})
```

Returned documents ensure all the conditions defined in `$and` brackets.